# Ruby Thor based executable with namespaces

Tags: ruby, namespaces, executable, thor

Is it possible to create a Thor based Ruby executable that accepts namespaces? To allow, for example, the following from the commandline: `./thorfile greet:formal`

Given I have the following thorfile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'thor'

class TalkTasks < Thor
  namespace       "talk"

  desc      "greet", "says hello"
  def greet
    puts "Hello!"
  end

  class Formal < Thor
    namespace "talk:formal"

    desc    "greet", "says a formal hello"
    def greet
      puts "Good evening!"
    end
  end

end

TalkTasks.start
```

This thorfile provides the following tasks (`thor -T`):

```
thor talk:formal:greet  # says a formal hello
thor talk:greet         # says hello
```

I can also use thorfile directly as an executable:

```
./thorfile greet
```

Which displays:

> Hello!

How can I get `./thorfile formal:greet` (or something similar) to execute the greet method in the Formal class, in order to display:

> Good evening!

Comment: Take a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663519/namespacing-thor-commands-in-a-standalone-ruby-executable

Answer (score 0):

Change the namespace for `Formal` class

```
class Formal < Thor
    namespace "formal"
    ...
end
```

You have nested the classes so the namespaces nest. If you separate them than you can do `talk:formal` hehe no time to test it. Should work.